What is the surface gradient of a scalar function defined only on a parametric surface
I'm working in the boundary elements framework. I have a surface $S$ which is defined by 2 parameters $\xi, \eta\in[-1, 1]$. Then the unknown of my problem is a scalar function $\phi:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R$ that I discretize using shape functions : on each element $S_e$ of $S$, I have
$$\phi^e=\sum_{p=1}^{n_e}M_p(\xi, \eta)\phi_p$$
I do the same for my geometry :
$$\mathbf Y^e(\xi, \eta)(=S^e(\xi, \eta))=\sum_{p=1}^{n_e}M_p(\xi, \eta)\mathbf Y_p$$
(which is just another way to tell that my surface is a parametric surface for each sub-surface)
The core equation of my problem involves the surface gradient $\mathbf\nabla_S$ of $\phi$. I want to express the "parametric surface gradient", which is the surface gradient of $\phi$ using my generalized coordinates $\xi$ and $\eta$. I know that the surface gradient is defined by :
$$\mathbf\nabla_S=\mathbf\nabla-\mathbf n\mathbf n$$
for any scalar function defined in a vicinity $V$ of $S$, because the standard gradient $\nabla$ has no sense if taken only on $S$. But here is my problem. The function $\phi$ is only defined on $S$, so how can I defined properly  my gradient surface ? I know the trick to define an auxiliary function $\hat\phi$ which is a prolongation of $\phi$ defined by
$$\begin{align}
\hat\phi:\mathbb R^3 & \rightarrow\mathbb R \\
\hat y\in\mathbb R^3\text{ (or $V(S)$)}& \mapsto \phi(P(\hat y))
\end{align}$$
where $P$ is the orthogonal projection of $\hat y$ onto $S$. Then the surface gradient of $\phi$ is just the standard gradient of $\hat\phi$ restricted on $S$. However I don't want to carry this orthogonal projection $P$ by hand and to implement it in my boundary element formulation. I just want a natural applicable expression of $\mathbf\nabla_S\phi$ using the parameters $\xi, \eta$. I don't know how to do it.
Thanks a lot for any kind of help.
Adrien.

Hello 1 month later lmao. I just found a way to define it properly and to compute it when the surface is defined by parametric coordinates : $$\mathbf y(\xi_1, \xi_2)\in S, \forall (\xi_1,\xi_2)\in\Delta,$$ when $\Delta$ is the reference/parametric space, for example $[-1, 1]^2$.
If we denote $\mathcal G$ the metric tensor and $g_{\alpha\beta}$ its coefficients, we have
$$\nabla_S \phi=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\xi_{\alpha}}g^{\alpha\beta}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial\xi_\beta}\cdot\mathbf e_r\right)\mathbf e_r$$
In the Einstein sum notation with repeated indices.
NB : $g^{\alpha\beta}$ are the double contravariant metric tensor coefficient, such that $g_{\alpha\beta}g^{\beta\alpha}=\delta_{\alpha\beta}$
This is explained in the book "Boundary Integral Equation Methods for Solids and Fluids" : https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1004795120236
